# Jasmine spyOn reporting functions have been called when they haven't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following code:

```
$scope.deleteJob = function(job) {
    SandboxService.deleteJob(job.id).then(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
            ngToast.success();
            $scope.refreshApps();
        }
        else {
            ngToast.danger();
        }
    });
};
```

And the following unit test:

```
it('should show success toast on delete and refresh apps', () => {
    spyOn(sandboxService, 'deleteJob').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({status: 500}));
    spyOn(ngToast, 'success');
    spyOn(scope, 'refreshApps');

    let mockJob = {
        'id': 1
    };

    scope.deleteJob(mockJob);

    sandboxService.deleteJob().then(() => {
        expect(ngToast.success).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.refreshApps).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Basically when deleting a job, if the delete was a success with a returned status of 200 then show a success toast and refresh, else show a danger toast.

I expect the test to fail, as it returns a status of 500, but it passes. This implies that `ngToast.success()` and `scope.refreshApps()` have been called.

I added some logs to the code, and it does return `status: 500` and go to the `else` block.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it possible that your spy has been called by another test? I usually instantiate the spys in a beforeEach method to make sure that every test gets the same condition

Comment: If I add focus to that one test (`fit`) it still succeeds so no other test could affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the asynchronous nature of `deleteJob`. Your `it` test ends even before `expect` is performed. Therefore you need some sort of synchronization. This could basically be done with `fakeAsync` and `tick` from `@angular/core/testing`.

```
it('should show success toast on delete and refresh apps', fakeAsync(() => {
    ...

    sandboxService.deleteJob();
    tick();

    expect(ngToast.success).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(scope.refreshApps).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

The problem however is that you're overwriting the original behaviour of `deleteJob` with the spy below, hence `ngToast.success` and `scope.refreshApps` won't be called and the test will fail.

```
 spyOn(sandboxService, 'deleteJob').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({status: 500}));
```

Comment: Thanks @uminder. This wasn't the solution I went with since I'm using angularJS 1.7 but your answer showed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@uminder's answer pointed out that the test was finishing before the `expect` functions were even called due the asynchronous nature - verified by adding some logs inside the test.

The solution was to add an argument to the test that is to be called when the test has finished: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

```
it('should show success toast on delete and refresh apps', (done) => {
    spyOn(sandboxService, 'deleteJob').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({status: 200}));
    spyOn(ngToast, 'success');
    spyOn(scope, 'refreshApps');

    let mockJob = {
        'id': 1
    };

    scope.deleteJob(mockJob);

    sandboxService.deleteJob().then(() => {
        expect(ngToast.success).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.refreshApps).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: glad it worked for you, using `done` is one of several ways dealing with asynchronous functions in `jasmine` unit tests.